# Wikipedia's Cayley Table and Pictures for 3 by 3 Permutation Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations

Are there any explanations or clarifications of the pictures at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix#Permutation_of_rows_and_columns?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Symmetric_group_3;_Cayley_table;_matrices.svg -
Are the black dots or red cells the entries of the matrix?

[image]

I can see the first matrix with the black filled circle is the identity.  But what about 1 to 5?
 Why are 1, 2, 5 green and 3, 4 white?

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix#Permutation_of_rows_and_columns
In the right picture for right permutation matrix multiplicaton, the black arrow runs through
 entry $(1, 1) \to (4, 4) \to (2, 2) \to (1,1) \to $ same permutation again.. .   How does this deal with $1 \to 2, 2 \to 4, 3 \to 1$ in $(2, 4, 3, 1)$? Thank you.

Comment: 3and 4 are transitive.

Comment: Red cells represent the 1's in the matrix, i.e. the $k$-th row of the $i$-th column is red iff the permutation sends $i$ to $k$.